# How to use session.uploadTask in background i am getting crash

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting crash

it says *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Completion handler blocks are not supported in background sessions. Use a delegate instead.'

```
var Boundary = "\(boundary.generateBoundaryString())_boundary"
private lazy var session: URLSession = {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MyUniqeId")
    config.isDiscretionary = true
    config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
    return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}()

func webServiceForUploadImages(urlStr:String,params:[String:String],fileUrl:String,imageData:Data,success :@escaping (AppMedia) -> Void ,failure:@escaping (NSError) -> Void) -> Void{
    let url = Constant.BASE_URL + urlStr
    print(url)
    if(reachAbility.connection != .none){
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = Header.headers()
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(Boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let data = try! createBody(with: params, filePathKey: "file", paths: [fileUrl], boundary: "\(Boundary)", imageData: imageData)

        session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data) { (data, response, err) in
            if response != nil{
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {return}
                handleError.shared.HandleReponseTokenExpireError(dataResponse: response, success: { (response) in
                })
                if(err != nil){
                    print("\(err!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                guard let responseData = data else {
                    print("no response data")
                    return
                }
                if let responseString = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let dict = Utility.jsonToDict(str: responseString)
                        let mediaDict = AppMedia(fromDictionary: dict as! [String : Any])
                        Constant.KAppDelegate.hideProgressHUD()
                        success(mediaDict)
                    }

                   // print("uploaded to: \(responseString)")
                }
            }else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    failure(err! as NSError)
                    Constant.KAppDelegate.hideProgressHUD()
                    Constant.KAppDelegate.showErrorMessage(title: "Error", message: Constant.ServerError, msgType: .error)
                }
            }

            }.resume()
    }else{
         self.showErrorMsg(str: Constant.ConnectivityError)
    }
}
```

let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MyUniqeId")
using this gives me crash

Comment: Issue is with success(mediaDict) and  failure(err! as NSError) completions......... 
instead sending session in background call your session in GCD if you are in need of completion blocks, If you are not  in need of completion block do as suggested in exception.

Comment: Hi Rob can you tell me how ??

Comment: You mean that i should use session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data).resume()

Comment: Though using this app still crashing

Comment: Ok I got you rob thanks a lot it's working

Comment: @AbuUlHassan can you give me any link for background call your session in GCD.

Comment: i have implemented in my projects let me post it as answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To upload using background `URLSessionConfiguration` there are a few special considerations:

1. Cannot use completion handlers (because the app might not be running when you finish the upload). You must use delegate-base methods, e.g. [`uploadTask(with:fromFile:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411550-uploadtask).

   For example:

   ```
    func startUpload(for request: URLRequest, from data: Data) throws -> URLSessionUploadTask {
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
            .appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
        let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileURL)
        task.resume()

        return task
    }
   ```

   That obviously assumes that you’ve specified your `delegate` and implemented the appropriate delegate methods:

   ```
    extension BackgroundSession: URLSessionDelegate {
        func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.savedCompletionHandler?()
                self.savedCompletionHandler = nil
            }
        }
    }

    extension BackgroundSession: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
        func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            print("success")
        }
    }
   ```
2. Note, we cannot use `uploadTask(with:from:)` because that’s using `Data` for that second parameter, which is not allowed for background sessions. Instead one must save the body of the request into a file and then use [`uploadTask(with:fromFile:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411550-uploadtask).
3. Remember to handle the scenario where the upload finishes when your app is not running. Namely, the app delegate’s `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` must capture the completion handler. For example, I’ll have a property in my `BackgroundSession` to save the completion handler:

   ```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { 
        BackgroundSession.shared.savedCompletionHandler = completionHandler
    }
   ```

   And then you want to implement `urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession:)` and call the saved completion handler:

   ```
    extension BackgroundSession: URLSessionDelegate {
        func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.savedCompletionHandler?()
                self.savedCompletionHandler = nil
            }
        }
    }
   ```

By the way, [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background) discusses many of these considerations (e.g. delegate API rather than closure based API, app delegate issues, etc.). It even discusses the requirements that upload tasks are file-based, too.

---

Anyway, here is a sample `BackgroundSession` manager:

```
import os.log

// Note, below I will use `os_log` to log messages because when testing background URLSession
// you do not want to be attached to a debugger (because doing so changes the lifecycle of an
// app). So, I will use `os_log` rather than `print` debugging statements because I can then
// see these logging statements in my macOS `Console` without using Xcode at all. I'll log these
// messages using this `OSLog` so that I can easily filter the macOS `Console` for just these
// logging statements.

private let log = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: #file)

class BackgroundSession: NSObject {
    var savedCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)?
    
    static var shared = BackgroundSession()
    
    private var session: URLSession!
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()

        let identifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".backgroundSession"
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: identifier)

        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }
}

extension BackgroundSession {
    @discardableResult
    func startUpload(for request: URLRequest, from data: Data) throws -> URLSessionUploadTask {
        os_log("%{public}@: start", log: log, type: .debug, #function)

        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
            .appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
        let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileURL)
        task.resume()

        return task
    }
}

extension BackgroundSession: URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
        os_log(#function, log: log, type: .debug)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.savedCompletionHandler?()
            self.savedCompletionHandler = nil
        }
    }
}

extension BackgroundSession: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            os_log("%{public}@: %{public}@", log: log, type: .error, #function, error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        os_log("%{public}@: SUCCESS", log: log, type: .debug, #function)
    }
}

extension BackgroundSession: URLSessionDataDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didBecome downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask) {
        os_log(#function, log: log, type: .debug)
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        os_log("%{public}@: received %d", log: log, type: .debug, #function, data.count)
    }
}
```

And, of course, my app delegate:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    ...

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        BackgroundSession.shared.savedCompletionHandler = completionHandler
    }
}
```

---

Needless to say, that’s a lot to worry about with uploads in conjunction with background `URLSession`. If you’re uploading huge assets (e.g. videos) over slow connections, perhaps you need that. But the other (simpler) alternative is to use a default `URLSession` configuration, and just tell the OS that even if the user leaves your app, request a little more time to finish the upload. Just use standard completion handler pattern with default `URLSession`, and marry that with the techniques outlined in [Extending Your App's Background Execution Time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time). Now, that only buys you 30 seconds or so (it used to be 3 minutes in older iOS versions), but often that’s all we need. But if you think it may take more than 30 seconds to finish the uploads, then you’ll need background `URLSessionConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MyUniqeId")
```

To

```
 let config = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
```

complete code will like below

```
 let config = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    var Boundary = "\(boundary.generateBoundaryString())_boundary"
    private lazy var session: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        config.isDiscretionary = true
        config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
        return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()
    func webServiceForUploadImages(urlStr:String,params:[String:String],fileUrl:String,imageData:Data,success :@escaping (AppMedia) -> Void ,failure:@escaping (NSError) -> Void) -> Void{
        let url = Constant.BASE_URL + urlStr
        print(url)
        if(reachAbility.connection != .none){
            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = Header.headers()
            request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(Boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let data = try! createBody(with: params, filePathKey: "file", paths: [fileUrl], boundary: "\(Boundary)", imageData: imageData)

            session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data) { (data, response, err) in
                if response != nil{
                    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {return}
                    handleError.shared.HandleReponseTokenExpireError(dataResponse: response, success: { (response) in
                    })
                    if(err != nil){
                        print("\(err!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    guard let responseData = data else {
                        print("no response data")
                        return
                    }
                    if let responseString = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let dict = Utility.jsonToDict(str: responseString)
                            let mediaDict = AppMedia(fromDictionary: dict as! [String : Any])
                            Constant.KAppDelegate.hideProgressHUD()
                            success(mediaDict)
                        }

                       // print("uploaded to: \(responseString)")
                    }
                }else{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        failure(err! as NSError)
                        Constant.KAppDelegate.hideProgressHUD()
                        Constant.KAppDelegate.showErrorMessage(title: "Error", message: Constant.ServerError, msgType: .error)
                    }
                }

                }.resume()
        }else{
             self.showErrorMsg(str: Constant.ConnectivityError)
        }
    }
```

now call it  in GCD in you viewController or what ever place you want.

```
     DispatchQueue.global().async {
    //  call your webServiceForUploadImages with completion blocks 
    }
```

**NOTE:**

***Only do if you are in need of completion blocks if completion blocks are not necessary do as suggested in exception use delegation***

Comment: Thanks @Abu Ul Hassan

Comment: Anyways i am not calling any completion in background.

Comment: private lazy var session: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "\(UUID().uuid).identifier")
        config.isDiscretionary = true
        config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
        return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()

Comment: what if you send one image and send 2nd image too even first is in progress ... your withIdentifier: "(UUID().uuid).identifier")  will match with 2nd request and bhom you have a problem

Comment: I am keeping separate UUId().uuid as i am getting break point in App delegate handleEvents .as I restart app .thanks..

Comment: try to run the scenario as e describe and lets see what happend.